# rails counting days if known dates, showing 0 on same date, would like to show 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can do this:

```
<%= (@go.end_date - @go.start_date).to_i %>
```

This will give me the number of dates, but granted, if it is the same date, it will output 0. I would like to output 1 instead. How do I make this show 1 instead of 0 for same dates?

Comment: What if dates differ in 1 day, what do you show then,  1?

Comment: Good point, then shouldn't it be two days? so in that case, shouldn't it just be +1 for all? I'm wondering if this is the conventional way. Say if you're traveling for 7/15 (today) and leaving tomorrow 7/16. Would that consider, 1 day or 2 days? I guess it depends on the time you left huh? Hmmmm I guess its all subjective?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you don't try with [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words)

This maybe works better for you

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words @go.start_date, @go.end_date %>
```

Comment: I think this would work best if I had time, but its only dates that I'm storing. I just tested this code, and if the start and end dates are the same, it shows "less than a minute"